# How to convert a floating number to fixed floating number using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, floating-point

For example, I want to calculate 3/6. 3/6 answer is a 0.5 floating number. When I fixed this number with the javascript toFixed(6) method it returned '0.500000'. The problem is that '0.500000' is a string. But I want a floating number with 6 digits after the dot(.). How can I do that? I tried this but it's won't work.

```
parseFloat((3/6).toFixed(6))
//output = 0.5 but i want 0.500000
```

Comment: You can't, `0.500000 === 0.5`. Why do you want to do this? Keeping it as a string is the approach you would need to take.

Comment: There is no such thing as a “fixed floating number.” “Fixed” is short for “fixed point,” and “floating” is short for “floating point.” The point is either fixed or floating; it cannot be both.

Comment: The floating-point format represents only numbers (or special NaN values). A number is an abstract mathematical entity; it has only its value, not digits. 13 is just 13, thirteen, 13.000, and binary 1101—those are all the same thing; “13”, “thirteen,” “13.000”, and “binary 1101” are text representations of the same number, 13. The floating-point format does not store either text or numbers of digits; it stores only a representation of the value. There is no way to store “0.500000” in the JavaScript Number format except as the number ½.

Answer (score 0):

Well,

```
parseFloat((3/6).toFixed(6))
//output = 0.5 means everything after .5 is 0
```

If you print it to the console it will remove the unnecessary zero. When you need to print up to 5 or 10 decimal points, you have to convert the number into a string using the toFixed method.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `toFixed` inside the `parseFloat()` because of that it is returning you `0.5`

Do this

```
let a = parseFloat((3/6).toFixed(6))
console.log(a)
```

Answer (score -1):

I updated my answer. I did not get that you wanted to use the output as a number. I don't think that what you want to achieve is possible. It's possible only if you keep you value as a string.

```
const numb = 3/6;
console.log(numb.toFixed(6));
```

For documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

Comment: `Number.parseFloat(3/6) === 3/6`, why use `parseFloat()` here?

Comment: Indeed. I updated my answer. Thanks for pointed it out.